# Dúvida sobre o uso de vírgula e dois pontos

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

Em alguns casos em que utilizo vírgula, vejo que o uso de dois pontos como pontuação poderia ser empregado também, pois adicionaria uma pausa que se encaixa com a entonação da frase. Seguem os exemplos:

> Para aprender a programar é necessário algumas práticas para estudar. Por exemplo, ler muito ajuda muito no processo e é uma das atitudes que pode ser adotada.
>
> Para aprender a programar é necessário algumas práticas para estudar. Por exemplo: ler muito ajuda muito no processo e é uma das atitudes que pode ser adotada.

Qual dos usos é o correto? Os dois casos são válidos?

Comment: Eu não poria nenhum deles, nesse exemplo concreto... estou curioso para ver as respostas, vou "estrelar" a pergunta. :)

Comment: Eu quase sempre utilizo dois pontos. Ao meu ver, o trecho encaixa como enumeração. Ps.: Confesso que fiquei curioso com o comentário do @ANeves. 

Comment: pra mim os dois pontos chamam um pouco atenção, como "a seguir tem algo importante" meio que inconscientemente...

Comment: eu coloco dois pontos quando há várias opções, pois vou usar a virgula para separar as opções no decorrer do tempo. E uso virgula, quando há apenas uma explicação ou exemplo. Não sei se é realmente essa a regra, mas é a que uso....

Comment: adicionando uma referência -> https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/dois-pontos-ou-virgula/1104

Answer (score 4):

Ambos estão corretos.

Os dois pontos [podem ser utilizados](https://www.normaculta.com.br/dois-pontos/):

> Antes de um **esclarecimento, explicação, resumo, causa ou consequência**:
>
> - E foi isso que aconteceu: elas foram embora mais cedo.
> - Resumindo: será necessário um esforço por parte de todos para que tudo funcione corretamente.

Inclusive, esta [página](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono31_2.php) sobre o tema usa os dois pontos antes de dar o exemplo para o uso dos dois pontos (e também no exemplo da observação após o exemplo):

> - Para indicar um esclarecimento, resultado ou resumo do que se disse.
>
>   **Exemplos**:
>
>   > Marcelo era assim mesmo: *não tolerava ofensas*.
>   > Resultado: *corri muito, mas não alcancei o ladrão*.
>   > Em resumo: *montei um negócio e hoje estou rico*.
>
>   Obs.: os dois-pontos costumam ser usados na introdução de exemplos, notas ou observações. Veja:
>
>   > Parônimos são vocábulos diferentes na significação e parecidos na forma.
>   > Exemplos:
>   > ratificar/retificar, censo/senso, etc.

Portanto, a sentença "Por exemplo: ler muito ajuda muito no processo" parece OK.

Mas também não parece haver problema com a versão com vírgula ao invés dos dois pontos ("Por exemplo, ler muito ajuda muito no processo"), uma vez que a vírgula [costuma ser usada](https://www.normaculta.com.br/virgula/) para isolar expressões como "por exemplo".

Answer (score 1):

De [Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/dois-pontos-ou-virgula/1104) [consultado em 21-05-2020]:

> I. – Vejamos o que dizem os seguintes autores sobre o emprego dos dois pontos:
>
> 1. – Jaime Rebelo (filólogo, pedagogo, professor do ensino secundário) em «Pontuação e Análise Sintáctica», 2.ª Edição:
>
> «A) Antes de orações que se podem transformar em integrantes, relativas, explicativas ou continuativas. – Os dois pontos precedem orações que se podem transformar em integrantes, relativas, explicativas ou continuativas».
>
> Seguidamente apresenta exemplos.
>
> «B) Substituem conjunções adversativas, causais, consecutivas ou conclusivas. – Os dois pontos substituem uma conjunção adversativa, causal, consecutiva ou conclusiva».
>
> Seguidamente apresenta exemplos.
>
> 2. – Rodrigo de Sá Nogueira (filólogo, professor do ensino secundário e depois universitário) em «Guia Alfabético de Pontuação»:
>
> «(...) considerados semanticamente, eles indicam: a) – que a frase que se lhes segue é a justificação daquilo que se enuncia na frase que os precede, e, em certos casos, substitui a conjunção causal'porque' (...) b) – que, em determinada lista de coisas ou de factos,eles (os dois pontos) substituem a expressão 'o seguinte'».
>
> Ilustra com exemplos as alíneas a) e b). E termina dizendo: «Em geral, empregam-se os dois pontos em seguida às expressões: a saber, o seguinte, tais são por exemplo (p. ex.), verbi gratia».